# Paste cell range to a single cell in mutiple lines

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste a range of cells into one cell in Excel.

```vba
Sub MergeSelectedRowData2()

    Dim MyCell As Range
    Dim strMerge As String

    For Each MyCell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2")

        If strMerge = "" Then
            strMerge = MyCell.Value
        Else
            strMerge = strMerge & Chr(32) & MyCell.Value
        End If

    Next MyCell

    Cells(1, 3).Value = strMerge

End Sub
```

This is the output
[image: Sample Image]

This is the output I want
[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the final code that i came up to and should output the desired result

```
Sub MergeSelectedRowData2()

Dim MyCell As Range
Dim strMerge(1 To 2) As Variant
Dim finalStr As String

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 2

    For Each MyCell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i & ":" & "B" & i)

        If strMerge(i) = "" Then
            strMerge(i) = MyCell.Value
        Else
            strMerge(i) = strMerge(i) & "   " & MyCell.Value
        End If

    Next MyCell

    If finalStr = "" Then
        finalStr = strMerge(i)
    Else
        finalStr = finalStr & Chr(10) & strMerge(i)
    End If

Next

Cells(1, 3).Value = finalStr
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Change to a line feed and it'll work - I've just tested this with your code.

```
strMerge = strMerge & Chr(10) & MyCell.Value
```

or for completion...

```
strMerge = strMerge & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & MyCell.Value
```

Edited to add macro

```
Range("C1").Select
    With Selection
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-2],RC[-1]) &  CHAR(10) & CHAR(13) & CONCATENATE(R[1]C[-2],R[1]C[-1])"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: however i still got the same output

Comment: i have changed the cell format to "Wrap Text" still the same

Comment: I've got this formula to work, it's limited to your example though.

`=CONCATENATE(A1,B1) &  CHAR(10) & CHAR(13) & CONCATENATE(A2,B2)`

Comment: There was no code, I used the above as a formula.

You could record a macro, paste this into your cell formula. You will need to have the Wrap Text box checked to make the presentation as you require it.

Added the macro "as is" in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

im fine with this using formula in excel. This is without using VBA

```
=A1 & CHAR(32) & B1 & CHAR(10) & A2 & CHAR(32) & B2
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess this solves my vba problem, pardon the poor programming style and naming
Call two foreach loop and join them (separating them with Chr(10))

```
Sub MergeSelectedRowData()

Dim MyCell As Range
Dim strMerge As String

Dim MyCell2 As Range
Dim strMerge2 As String

For Each MyCell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B1")

    If strMerge = "" Then
        strMerge = MyCell.Value
    Else
        strMerge = strMerge & Chr(32) & MyCell.Value
    End If

Next MyCell

For Each MyCell2 In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B2")

    If strMerge2 = "" Then
        strMerge2 = MyCell2.Value
    Else
        strMerge2 = strMerge2 & Chr(32) & MyCell2.Value
    End If

Next MyCell2

Cells(1, 3).Value = strMerge & Chr(10) & strMerge2
```

End Sub